# changing thread priority and scheduler in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

I have a single threaded application. If i use below code, i get `sched_setscheduler(): Operation not permitted`
.

```
struct sched_param param;
param.sched_priority = 1;
if (sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_RR, &param))
printf(stderr, "sched_setscheduler(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

But, if i use pthread api such as below, i dont get an error. What is the difference between the two for a single threaded application and is the below function really changing the scheduler and priority or am i missing some error handling?

```
void assignRRPriority(int tPriority)
{
    int  policy;
    struct sched_param param;

    pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &param);
    param.sched_priority = tPriority;
    if(pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &param))
            printf("error while setting thread priority to %d", tPriority);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error may be caused by a limit set on realtime priority (`ulimit -r` to check, `ulimit -r 99` to allow 1-99 priorities). As of `pthread_setschedparam` being successful: if you compiled without `-pthread` option, this function is just a stub, like some other pthread functions. With `-pthread` option, the results should be identical (`strace` shows that the same system call is used).

Comment: 1. I did link the application with -lpthread. 2. ulimit -r shows 0. so how does it explain that i am able to call the function assignRRPriority with value of 80. Why is that not erroring out?

Comment: `-lpthread` is not enough, `-pthread` is required (for _both_ compiling _and_ linking). Then assignRRPriority will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some basic error handling. You need some < in there. Try this:

```
if(pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &param) < 0) {
  perror("pthread_setschedparam");
}
```